# How can i change OS setup screen?

Tags: boot, screen, startup

I want to make changes to this screen that we saw when installing Ubuntu. Which directory do I need to modify? What exactly is this screen called? What exactly can I say to this screen? I've tried a few different words, but I haven't found the words I can explain.

[I want to change this screen - Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUqXx.png)

[I want to change this screen - Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kPe7.jpg)

Comment: That is the Ubiquity installer, the source code is available for your modifications at launchpad.net. Ubiquity is not included in the installed system.

Comment: So what should I call the name if I want to change it in another operating system? What exactly is this section called in other systems?

Comment: Your first step is to locate the Ubiquity project at Launchpad.net. Next, download the source code. Then make your changes. Then compile your changed source code. Finally, test your newly-compiled version of Ubiquity.

Comment: Thank you very much! @user535733